# Developing RESTful API and getting error while using Postman framework to test web API

Tags: java, rest, postman

I have written a small demo program to develop RESTful API and I am using Postman framework to test my web API. The GET request works fine but the POST request gives an error.  I have added the error message by Postman framework at the end of the code.

```
This is my model class named Message

package com.abc.model;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement  
public class Message {

private long id;
private String msg;
private String author;
private Date date;

public Message() {

}

public Message(long id, String msg, String author, Date date) {
    this.id = id;
    this.msg = msg;
    this.author = author;
    this.date = date;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}


public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getMsg() {
    return msg;
}

public void setMsg(String msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}


public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}


public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}


public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

}

Instead of using Hibernate/Database tables, I have created a class called Database class 

package com.abc.database;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.abc.model.Message;

public class DatabaseTable {
//Any class in the application can access map of messages and profiles by calling these static methods( getMessages())

private static Map<Long, Message> messages =new HashMap<>();


public static Map<Long,Message> getMessages() {
    return messages;
    }

}

This is my service class

package com.abc.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Date;

import com.abc.database.DatabaseTable;
import com.abc.model.Message;

public class MessageService {

    private Map<Long, Message> messages = DatabaseTable.getMessages();

    public MessageService(){
    messages.put(1L, new Message(1,"This is a message from Ridh","Ridhi", new Date()));
    messages.put(2L, new Message(2,"Message from Steve", "Steve", new Date()));
}       

    public List<Message> fetchMessages() {
        return new ArrayList<Message>(messages.values());
    }


    public Message retrieveMessage(long id) {
        return messages.get(id);
    }


    public Message addMessage(Message message) {
        message.setId(messages.size() + 1);
        messages.put(message.getId(), message);
        return message;
    }

    public Message updateMessage(Message message){
        messages.put(message.getId(),message);
        return message;
    }

    public Message deleteMessage(long id){
        return messages.remove(id);
    }
}

This is my Resource class calling the service


package com.abc.resource;

import javax.ws.rs.Path;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.abc.service.MessageService;

@Path("/messages")
public class MainResource {

    MessageService ms = new MessageService();

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
    public List<Message> display()
    return ms.fetchMessages();
    }


    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Message addMessage(Message message) {  
        return ms.addMessage(message);
    }
}

This is the web.xml 


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>RestWebService</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Rest Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Rest Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/HelloREST/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

This is the pom.xml of my project

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>RestWebService</groupId>
    <artifactId>RestWebService</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
     <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>8.5.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.38</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring ORM -->
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>


<!-- Apache Commons DBCP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

<!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>




<!-- Logging -->
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>


    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
Error message( Postman framework)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Apache Tomcat/8.0.32 - Error report</title>
        <style type="text/css">H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}.line {height: 1px; background-color: #525D76; border: none;}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception</h1>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <p>
            <b>type</b> Exception report
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>message</b>
            <u>Servlet execution threw an exception</u>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>description</b>
            <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>exception</b>
        </p>
        <pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
</pre>
        <p>
            <b>root cause</b>
        </p>
        <pre>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory
    com.sun.jersey.json.impl.reader.JsonXmlStreamReader.create(JsonXmlStreamReader.java:110)
    com.sun.jersey.json.impl.Stax2JsonFactory.createReader(Stax2JsonFactory.java:137)
    com.sun.jersey.json.impl.Stax2JsonFactory.createReader(Stax2JsonFactory.java:127)
    com.sun.jersey.json.impl.BaseJSONUnmarshaller.createXmlStreamReader(BaseJSONUnmarshaller.java:116)
    com.sun.jersey.json.impl.BaseJSONUnmarshaller.unmarshalJAXBElementFromJSON(BaseJSONUnmarshaller.java:111)
    com.sun.jersey.json.impl.BaseJSONUnmarshaller.unmarshalFromJSON(BaseJSONUnmarshaller.java:100)
    com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider.readFrom(JSONRootElementProvider.java:154)
    com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.readFrom(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:111)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:490)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:123)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:86)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:183)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
</pre>
        <p>
            <b>root cause</b>
        </p>
        <pre>java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1308)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1142)
    com.sun.jersey.json.impl.reader.JsonXmlStreamReader.create(JsonXmlStreamReader.java:110)
    com.sun.jersey.json.impl.Stax2JsonFactory.createReader(Stax2JsonFactory.java:137)
    com.sun.jersey.json.impl.Stax2JsonFactory.createReader(Stax2JsonFactory.java:127)
    com.sun.jersey.json.impl.BaseJSONUnmarshaller.createXmlStreamReader(BaseJSONUnmarshaller.java:116)
    com.sun.jersey.json.impl.BaseJSONUnmarshaller.unmarshalJAXBElementFromJSON(BaseJSONUnmarshaller.java:111)
    com.sun.jersey.json.impl.BaseJSONUnmarshaller.unmarshalFromJSON(BaseJSONUnmarshaller.java:100)
    com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider.readFrom(JSONRootElementProvider.java:154)
    com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.readFrom(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:111)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:490)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:123)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:86)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:183)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
</pre>
        <p>
            <b>note</b>
            <u>The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.32 logs.</u>
        </p>
        <hr class="line">
        <h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.32</h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Edit the code part to show only relevant portions

Answer (score 0):

Could you please add the dependency for `jackson-mapper-asl` in the dependency section of your pom.xml. For example you may add the following in pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you Sanjeev Saha. The POST request works fine after adding the jackson-mapper-asl dependency. 
But when I use PUT request on Postman for the update method
 it gives a 404 error. Do i need to add another dependency?